# Як перекласти "Hello world"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

"Hello World" — це фраза, яка широко використовується програмістами при вивченні мов програмування. Найпростіша програма просто виводить цю фразу, після чого закінчує свою роботу.

Також ця фраза може використовуватися для демонстрації мінімального словосполучення взагалі. Ось, деякий час тому я [намалював](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1691/1009) діаграму визначення мови на основі [іншої діаграми](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGiHK.png) з сайту Habrahabr.

[image: Identifying Language diagram]

Мені не дуже подобається відсутність кличного відмінку і відсутність коми перед зверненням. Грубо кажучи, це не зовсім українська. :)

Запитання: **Як правильно написати "Hello World" українською?**

Comment: Там не всіма мовами є слово «світ»: грузинською лише «привіт», а дравідськими мовами там не переклад, а транслітерація: тамільською лише «halo:», каннада «halo: varld», телуґу «halo varald». А вірменською навпаки, лише «світ» (ashkharh).

Comment: Як щодо *привіт світові*? Хоча в оригіналі стоїть звертання, але, на мою думку, так гарніше звучить.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Оскільки, фраза виявляє звертання, а в українській мові при звертанні потрібно використовувати [кличний відмінок](http://posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/u_m/1.htm), то правильно писати - **"Привіт, світе"**. Кома використовується для виділення звертання.

> Іменники – власні та загальні назви – можуть мати в кличному відмінку однини закінчення -о, -е, -є, -у, -ю. Вибір одного із цих закінчень залежить від роду іменника та його закінчення в називному відмінку, а за умови спільного нульового закінчення – від кінцевого приголосного основи або ж характеру іменникового суфікса.
>
> **Форму із закінченням -е мають:**
>   - Іменники – власні та загальні назви чоловічого роду з твердим кінцевим приголосним основи (зокрема й основи на -р твердої та мішаної групи), що виступає перед нульовим закінченням або закінченням -о: адвокате, програмісте і т.д.
>
> **Кома в реченнях:**
>   В сучасній українській мові [кома](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA)#.D0.92_.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.97.D0.BD.D1.81.D1.8C.D0.BA.D1.96.D0.B9_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.96) вживається на письмі для відокремлення однорідних членів речення, звертань, вставних слів, виділення порівнянь і зворотів, відокремлення частин складних речень.
>   - *Слався, мій народе, мій гордий, чесний, добрий, молодий
>
>   —Микола Вінграновський*

*Також декому може бути корисним наступне [відео](https://youtu.be/WRdl08mK5gs) про розділові знаки при звертаннях.*

Answer (score 6):

> У школах сім десятків мов —
>                   навчати школярів охайних.
>   Тепер закон для всіх один —
>                   **вітаю, світе мій коханий**.
>   Змужніле між негод життя
>                   (хай скільки серце помилялось!) —
>   Мій мозок зцілить і введе
>                   у творче річише зухвалість…
>
> *<sub>[Давид Гофштейн «Біля мого вікна» в перекладі Валерії Богуславської (уривок; до речі, можливо, це останній з творів Давида Гофштейна).](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=qas6lfYyXOQC&pg=PT383&dq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E+%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22)</sub>*

> Добрався вже до першого листя, заплющив очі й каже:
>
> — **Ну, світе, здоров був!** Або виграю, або програю!
>
> І з заплющеними очима скочив на перший лист.
>
> *<sub>[Казка «Дерево до неба».](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=qas6lfYyXOQC&pg=PT383&dq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E+%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22)</sub>*

«**Здоров був, світе!**» (2005) — назва одного з фільмів українського режисера [Дмитра Мойсеєва](http://screenplay.com.ua/authors/?id=35).